# Recursive generalized pseudoinverse

Tags: inverse, pseudoinverse

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{\text{n$\times$m}}$ be a rectangular matrix, and $n,m\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}$. The generalized pseudo-inverse $A^g$ is defined as $AA^gA = A$. The computation complexity of the generalized pseudo-inverse would grow rapidly as dimension $n,m$ grow. I wonder if there is any recursive method to calculate $A^g$ from matrix $A$ without involving inversion. Maybe at a form of
$$A^g_{k} = f_1(A,A^g_{k-1}) + f_2(A,A^g_{k-1})$$
where $f_1,f_2$ are some non-complex operations given some initialization $A^g_{0}$. Thank you!

Comment: "The computation complexity of the generalized pseudo-inverse would grow exponentially..." Does it? Standard inverses can be calculated in [better than $O(n^3)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations#Matrix_algebra)

Comment: @Wouter Thank you for the comment. "Exponentially" is not a correct choice of word. I have edited the question.